# How to enable Secrets encryption on EKS cluster?

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-kms

I use the Terraform EKS module, [terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks) (version: 18.30.1). I would like to enable Secrets encryption for EKS cluster. I added lines as follows in my code.

```
  create_kms_key  = true
  kms_key_description = "KMS Secrets encryption for EKS cluster."
  kms_key_enable_default_policy   = true
```

After I terraform apply, the "Secrets encryption" is still off. I read the document. No clue what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. Lines as follows solved the problem.

```
  create_kms_key                  = true
  cluster_encryption_config = [{
    resources = ["secrets"]
  }]

  kms_key_description             = "KMS Secrets encryption for EKS cluster."
  kms_key_enable_default_policy   = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Terraform module, besides setting those variables you need to specify a `cluster_encryption_config` variable as well, as there's a dynamic block:

```
  dynamic "encryption_config" {
    for_each = toset(var.cluster_encryption_config)

    content {
      provider {
        key_arn = var.create_kms_key ? module.kms.key_arn : encryption_config.value.provider_key_arn
      }
      resources = encryption_config.value.resources
    }
  }
```

Given that the default value for the [variable cluster_encryption_config](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/variables.tf#L89-L93) is set to an empty list, the dynamic block is empty too.